# React-table server-side not loading data

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-table

I'm trying to replicate the server side react-table on my local. here's what i got so far.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactTable from "react-table";
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalSize, setTotalSize] = useState(0);
  const [sortFieldQuery, setSortFieldQuery] = useState("");
  const [sortOrderQuery, setSortOrderQuery] = useState("asc");
  const [sizePerPageQuery, setSizePerPageQuery] = useState(10);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const doFetch = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schools")
          .then(res => {
            setData(res.data.data);
            setTotalSize(res.meta.total);
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    }
    doFetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ReactTable
      columns={[
        {
          Header: "First Name",
          accessor: "firstName"
        },
        {
          Header: "Last Name",
          id: "lastName",
          accessor: d => d.lastName
        },
        {
          Header: "Age",
          accessor: "age"
        }
      ]}
      data={data}

    />
  )
} export default App;
```

when i  run the browser, it produce error like this
[image: Please see image here]

i'm scratching my head as I don't know where my errors are.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be happening because `export default App` place.

Instead of

```
const App = () =>{
....

} export default App;
```

Please follow below.

```
const App = () =>{
...
};


export default App;
```

Comment: When i change the code above, I get the error " Parsing error: Only expressions, functions or classes are allowed as the `default` export."

Comment: still got the error. i already put the spaces on it.

Comment: Please use `;` between `}` and `export`

Comment: same Error. i think the problem is on the react-table plugin, but i cant seem to identify what specific problem in that part.

Comment: If your react-table version is above `>7`, please use `useTable` hook to get the functions and render the table. Kindly refer this link for more info https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic

Comment: I will try to use the `useTable`, will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using react table next since i cant get it to work.